# PS3joy six axis with bluetooth keyboard and mouse

Tags: ros, bluetooth, ps3joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just wondering if anyone has tried to use the ps3joy package with a bluetooth keyboard and mouse and run into the issue I am having.  The instructions on the wiki detail how to allow the ps3 controller to pass through the operating system and let the ps3joy.py script access it, but that involves disabling all bluetooth input devices.  Does anyone know a better way, maybe disabling only the playstation device instead of all bluetooth input devices?

I've looked around on google, but with little success.

Here are some of the ROS wiki links:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ps3joy/KarmicInstructions#Disable_interception_of_HID_devices_by_bluetoothd
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ps3joy/Tutorials/PairingJoystickAndBluetoothDongle

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9057/ps3joy-six-axis-with-bluetooth-keyboard-and-mouse/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At least one person has reported success just trying to use their
bluetooth keyboard with ps3joy. My interpretation is that the keyboard
must have been in HID proxy mode, which would get intercepted by the
dongle, and forwarded as a USB connection. If you can get your
keyboard and mouse into HID proxy mode, you should be fine. I have no
idea how to do that, though.

Getting the existing ps3joy.py to coexist with real bluetooth HID
devices is really not an easy option, unfortunately. (I can elaborate
if you want to attack the problem, but it is pretty non-trivial.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1